# How can I get macOS desktop notifications from Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, google-chrome

Maybe a browser extension, or a desktop application?

Comment: StackPop may be ancient, it still works just fine: [Stackpop — Stack Exchange meets OS X Notification Center](https://stackapps.com/q/4523)

Comment: @MartijnPieters download link is outdated, doesn't work anymore. Any other advice?

Comment: Nope, sorry, no idea.

Comment: The source code is still live at https://bitbucket.org/jacobbudin/stackpop/, but beyond downloading the project and compiling yourself in XCode, there doesn't seem to be a great option for Stackpop specifically. There's no archives of that link to the zipped app on archive.org either, unfortunately.